# Find the right and left cosets of H = {(1), (123), (132)} in S4

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know  $S_4=\{(),(3,4),(2,3),(2,3,4),(2,4,3),(2,4),(1,2),(1,2)(3,4),(1,2,3),(1,2,3,4),(1,2,4,3),(1,2,4),(1,3,2),(1,3,4,2),(1,3),(1,3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,3,2,4),(1,4,3,2),(1,4,2),(1,4,3),(1,4),(1,4,2,3),(1,4)(2,3) \}$ and I know there are 8 cosets to be found (I could be wrong) since $24 \div 3=8$ but I have trouble finding out how solve this. Can someone please help? I don't understand how I should multiply each $H$ with the corresponding S₄.

Comment: Choose a permutation not in $H$ and then multiply it on the right of every element in $H$ or on the left (not both at the same time).

Comment: whoops, my algebra is rusty. Thought cosets still had to be subgroups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For example:**
$$
(34)H = \{(34)(1),(34)(123),(34)(132)\} = \{(34),(124),(1432)\}
$$
is the left coset of $H$ associated with $(3,4)$.  We "multiply $H$" by (in this case, left-) multiplying each element in $H$ by the relevant element of $S_4$.

Note that some cosets end up being the same.  For example,
$$
[(34)(123)]H = (124)H = \{(124),(1432),(34)\} = (34)H
$$

You are indeed correct about the number of (distinct) cosets; this is a consequence of Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  If not, could you clarify on where this falls short?  Do you need elaboration on how to multiply elements?

Comment: This helps a lot . Multiplying the elements kinda throws me off so can you check if this right ? (23)H gives {(23),(13),(12)}?

Comment: That's right.  To help with multiplying: try decomposing into cycles straight off.  So, for example, to multiply $(23)(132)$:
$$
\begin{cases}
1 \overset{(132)}{\to} 3 \overset{(23)}{\to} 2\\
2 \to 1 \to 1 
\end{cases} \implies (12) \text{ is one of the cycles}\\
3 \to 2 \to 3 \implies (3) \text{ is one of the cycles}
$$