# Find a set of representatives of cosets in $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

**Problem:** Find a set of representative of the left cosets of $H$ in $S_4$, where $H = \left\{ \sigma \in S _ { 4 } \mid \sigma ( 4 ) = 4 \right\}$.

**Solution:** In the case of $S _ { 4 }$ we have $\{ \mathrm { id } , ( 14 ) , ( 24 ) , ( 34 ) \}$ as a set of representatives (or transversal).

I have trouble understanding intuitively the concept of cosets. I do understand that a representative is a member of the coset. How $(14)$ is a representative of a coset in $S_4$? What coset is it representing?

Comment: This is a very typical question when learning cosets. Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940810/find-the-right-and-left-cosets-of-h-1-123-132-in-s4).

Comment: The intuition here is that any two $g_1, g_2 \in S_4$ are in the same left-coset iff $g_1(4) = g_2(4)$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Thank you very much, that the idea I was looking for!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for this link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1\,4)$ is a  representative of the left coset… $(1\,4)H$.

Also, two permutations $\rho,\sigma\in S_4$  define the same coset modulo $H$ if and only if $\rho^{-1}\sigma\in H$, i.e. if the composition  $\rho^{-1}\sigma$ leaves $4$ fixed. Now you can easily check this condition is not satisfied by any of the pairs $\{\operatorname{Id}, (1\,4), (2\,4), (3\,4)\}$, e.g.
$$(1\,4)(2\,4)=(1\,4\,2)$$
Finally, observe $H$ is isomorphic to $S_3$ (it permutes $1,2,3$ between them). So the set $S_4/H$ has cardinal
$$\bigl|S_4/H\bigr|=\frac{\bigl|S_4\bigr|}{\bigl|S_3\bigr|}=4,$$
  so we've obtained the exact number of cosets representatives.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying to understand how the set of representative was found and you explained it really well.
@Bernard how the criteria $\rho , \sigma \in S _ { 4 }$ define the same coset modulo $H$ if and only if $\rho ^ { - 1 } \sigma \in H$ can be extended to group actions?

Comment: I don't understand very well what situation in group actions your question refers to? Could explain with more details?

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake, it wasn't about group actions but quotient groups. Let $G$ a finite group, $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$, we know that $G/H$ (the set of all cosets of H in G) is a group. 
To expand on your comment, can we say that $g_1$ and $g_2$ define the same coset modulo H if and only if $g_1 ^{-1} g_2 \in H$?

Comment: Yes absolutely. The only difference is that $G/H$ is a group when $H$ is a normal subgroup, and that left cosets are the same as right cosets.